# Trying to return to "Presenter Mode" in powerpoint after a hyperlink to a website

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, hyperlink

I have created a ppt presentation with internal and external hyperlinks.  When the selected external link takes me to a webpage, I want to be able to jump back into presenter mode when done viewing the webpage. Currently, I have to reselect the ppt application. PPT brings me back to the slide mode with a dialogue box that asks if I want to return to slide show. Is there a way to keep ppt in slide show mode without having to click the dialogue box?  Thank you.

Comment: Which version of PowerPoint are you using? I tested it on Win 10 with PowerPoint 365 and 2016, but I did not encounter a dialog box.

Comment: You may have accidentally switched to the normal PPT window and clicked on something; that would provoke the message you described. When you're done viewing the hyperlinked web page, simply close the browser and you'll be returned to PPT's slideshow view. Or, if you must leave the browser open, use ALT+TAB to switch back to PPT.  This assumes Windows; Mac thinks different but there should be a similar command.